# Segmented control customization

Tags: swift, customization, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to implement segmented control in my app and I want to customize it.

Is there any way to make segment look like this green trapezium?
[image: example]

Comment: This is not usable as a segmented control. It does not contain segments.

Comment: @Mundi 
Let me reprhase myself. Is it possible to make a segment look like trapezium or not?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12273369/730701). It is on objective-c but the rule stays the same. However, it is a bit tricky and sometimes it is more worth to implement a custom control instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this!